# "First day after expiration date" term

Tags: terminology

What term can be used to define the first day of the time interval where an item expires?
For example, my driving license expires on 2015.01.31; the date of 2015.02.01 is "first day of invalidity" or "first day after expiration date".

Comment: It seems to me that you'd just say it.  Unless you're George Carlin, in which case you invent "manubaday" or some such.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. But I wonder on what date you'd say the license expired. I'd think that with an expiration date of 2015.01.31, the license is expired starting 2015.02.01. Is that common English language? Or, on 2015.01.31 you'd say "My license expires today", but the day after you'd say "My license expired".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's some context which requires great precision, I would say

> The day after my licence expires

Answer (score 2):

> My driving licence is invalid from ...

I would use such a phrase when describing my vacation:

> I shall be on vacation and unavailable for queries from